# converting Wildcard to Regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, wildcard

I'm new in MVC, I want to perform Wildcard (*, ?) search on database. This is what I have done by using Regex:

**Controller:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;


namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        CrossWord_dbEntities db = new CrossWord_dbEntities();

        public ActionResult Index(string searching)
        {
            if (searching == null)
            {
                searching = "*";
            }
            string regEx = WildcardToRegex(searching);
            return View(db.tbl_values.ToList().Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, regEx, RegexOptions.Singleline)));            
        }

        public static string WildcardToRegex(string pattern)
        {
            return "^" + Regex.Escape(pattern).
            Replace("\\*", ".*").
            Replace("\\?", ".") + "$";
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.tbl_values>

<br /><br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
@Html.TextBox("searching") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Results</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="color:red">
                    No Result 
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </tbody>

</table>
```

i have in my database three recordes: Hello, Hero, Shalom

when i type " H* " i get the result: Hello, Hero - this works great
but when i type " *lom " i get "No Result" instead of "Shalom"
or when i type " Hell?" i get "No Result" instead of "Hello"

what i did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
Expression<Func<tbl_value, bool>> query = m =>
SqlFunctions.PatIndex(searching.ToLower().Replace("*", "%"), m.Name.ToLower()) > 0;

var details = db.tbl_values.Where(query);
```

Hope this will help you